# Plotting in the "Manipulate" function - simple coding

Tags: plotting, graphics, programming, manipulate

Hello Mathematica community, my name is Preston!

I have a real quick question that should be easy to answer.  Alright, so for a research project that I'm involved it at my university, I need to illustrate the outline of a Cassini Oval using something I've been calling "concentric circles" - but that doesn't really matter.  I've decided to use Mathematica in my research.  I used the "Manipulate" function in order to illustrate what these "concentric circles" would do as their radii varied over a specific interval.  Here's the code for that:

```
    Manipulate[
    Graphics[{Circle[{-1, 0}, H], Circle[{1, 0}, 1.2/H]}, 
    Axes -> True], {H, Sqrt[1.2 + 1] - 1, Sqrt[1.2 + 1] + 1}]
```

That is all fine and good, and it does exactly what I want.  However, I really need to somehow plot the curve of the following function in the Manipulate:

```
    [(x+1)^2+y^2]*[(x-1)^2+y^2]=(1.2)^2
```

So, basically, as the manipulator runs, I want the "concentric circles" to do what they do, but I want the function I just listed to just sit still.  The idea is that as the "concentric circles" change over the interval defined for $H$, their intersection will outline a Cassini Oval (the equation above).

I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thanks!  Also, what I'm trying to do may be illustrated in the following code:

```
     x = Table[{(-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2), Sqrt[1 - H^2 + (2 H^2 (-1 + H^4))/(4 H^2) - 
         H^2 ((-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2))^2]/H}, {H, 1, 1 + Sqrt[2], 0.01}];

    x1 = Table[{(-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2), -(Sqrt[1 - H^2 + (2 H^2 (-1 + H^4))/(4 H^2) - 
         H^2((-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2))^2]/H)}, {H, 1, 1 + Sqrt[2], 0.01}];

    x2 = Table[{-((-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2)), Sqrt[1 - H^2 + (2 H^2 (-1 + H^4))/(4 H^2) - 
         H^2 ((-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2))^2]/H}, {H, 1, 1 + Sqrt[2], 0.01}];

    x3 = Table[{-((-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2)), -(Sqrt[1 - H^2 + (2 H^2 (-1 + H^4))/(4 H^2) - 
         H^2 ((-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2))^2]/H)}, {H, 1, 1 + Sqrt[2], 0.01}];

     m =
         Manipulate[
             Graphics[{Green, Circle[{1, 0}, 1/H], Blue, Circle[{-1, 0}, H], 
             Black, {BezierCurve[x]}, {BezierCurve[x1]}, 
             {BezierCurve[x2]}, {BezierCurve[x3]}}, Axes -> True], {H, 1/(Sqrt[2] + 1), 
             Sqrt[2] + 1}]
```

This is something I did for a trivial Cassini Oval with constant product equal to 1.  It sort of does what I want, but it's way to complicated and glitchy.  I want to know if a more evolved code is possible.

Comment: By the way, "concentric" means having the same centre, which your circles don't. I suggest choosing a different terminology :-)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  Can you edit your profile and set your name, so it's something easier to remember than user11781?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ContourPlot` to draw the function and `Show` to combine it with the other graphics:

```
With[{p = 
   ContourPlot[((x + 1)^2 + y^2)*((x - 1)^2 + y^2) == (1.2)^2, 
     {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> False]}, 
 Manipulate[
  Show[p, Graphics[{Circle[{-1, 0}, H], Circle[{1, 0}, 1.2/H]}, 
    Axes -> True]], {H, Sqrt[1.2 + 1] - 1, Sqrt[1.2 + 1] + 1}]]
```

[image]

To show the Cassini Oval being drawn as you move the slider, I would suggest using a `ParametricPlot`. First use `Solve` to obtain a parametric description of the curve:

```
sol = {x, y} /. Solve[{
     ((x + 1)^2 + y^2) == h^2,
     ((x - 1)^2 + y^2) == (1.2/h)^2},
    {x, y}];
```

Then put a parametric plot of `sol` into the `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[sol, {h, Sqrt[1.2 + 1] - 1, H},
  Epilog -> {Circle[{-1, 0}, H], Circle[{1, 0}, 1.2/H],
    PointSize[Large], Point[sol /. h -> H]},
  PlotRange -> 4, PlotStyle -> Thick],
 {H, $MachineEpsilon + Sqrt[1.2 + 1] - 1, Sqrt[1.2 + 1] + 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Simon!  This is very helpful!

Comment: Also, and this may be stretching, but is it possible to create an animation where the "concentric circles" outline the shape of the Cassini Oval with their intersections as $H$ varies over its interval?  I.E as $H=1$ maybe 1/3 of the Cassini Oval is outlined, when $H=\sqrt{1.2+1}+1$ the oval is completely outlined.

Comment: Thanks again, Simon!  Sorry about the late reply.  This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is to define a single function (here called `f`) that encapsulates all four of the portions of your curve.

```
f[j_, i_] := Table[{j (-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2), i Sqrt[1 - H^2 + (2 H^2 (-1 + H^4))/(4 H^2) - 
                    H^2 ((-1 + H^4)/(4 H^2))^2]/H}, {H, 1, 1 + Sqrt[2], 0.01}];
Manipulate[Graphics[{Green, Circle[{1, 0}, 1/H], Blue, Circle[{-1, 0}, H], 
   Black, BezierCurve[f[1, 1]], BezierCurve[f[1, -1]], 
          BezierCurve[f[-1, 1]], BezierCurve[f[-1, -1]]}, Axes -> True], 
   {H, 1/(Sqrt[2] + 1), Sqrt[2] + 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Bill!  I'd rate you up, but I'm too new :(.